# How to remove `tns` prefix from elements in xsd schema inserted into wsdl?

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have wsdl where xsd inserted. It looks like:

[image]

The question is quite simple, but i can not find decision:
How to remove `tns` profix from the `login` and `password` elements?

When i tried to remove `tns` appears automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I just remove `elementFormDefault="qualified"` from

```
<xsi:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:altova="http://www.altova.com/xml-schema-extensions" targetNamespace="http://new.webservice.namespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

in WSDL and now there is no `tns` prefix.
Or change `"qualified"` to `"unqualified"`.